# Is there something similar to the Severity enumeration in the BCL?

Tags: .net

Simple question. :) Is there an equivalent to the [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Package.Severity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.package.severity.aspx) enumeration in the .NET Framework Base Class Library (BCL)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is:

[System.Diagnostics.TraceLevel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelevel.aspx)
[System.Diagnostics.SourceLevels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.sourcelevels.aspx)

Comment: Not quite the same, `Off` doesn't really make sense as a severity. Any idea if there are better options available today?